# There exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ surjective such that $f^{-1}(n)$ is infinite for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ surjective such that $f^{-1}(n)$ is infinite for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How can I define an function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. ?

Answer (score 4):

An easy possible solution is given by $f(x,y) = x$.